# Pick and move a node in a pannable/zoomable Pane

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am trying to place a few components inside a `ScrollPane`. These components should have the ability to be moved across this pane by mouse (click and drag). The `ScrollPane` itself is pannable and zoomable.

Now if I pick one of them and drag it to a new position the mouse is faster than the component if I have zoomed out. When zoomed in, the component gets moved faster than the mouse movement.

If not zoomed it works until I reach a certain position where the `ScrollPane` automatically pans.

It must have to do something with the determined coordinates of the nodes. Does anyone have an idea what I have to add to make it work correctly?

My controller class:

```
public class MainWindowController implements Initializable {

    private final double SCALE_DELTA = 1.1;
    private final StackPane zoomPane = new StackPane();
    private Group group = new Group();

    @FXML
    private ScrollPane scrollPane;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        Node node1 = new Node("Test");
        Node node2 = new Node("Test2", 100, 200);

        group.getChildren().addAll(node1, node2);
        zoomPane.getChildren().add(group);
        Group scrollContent = new Group(zoomPane);
        scrollPane.setContent(scrollContent);
        scrollPane.viewportBoundsProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Bounds> observable,
                Bounds oldValue, Bounds newValue) -> {
                    zoomPane.setMinSize(newValue.getWidth(), newValue.getHeight());
                });

        zoomPane.setOnScroll(
                (ScrollEvent event) -> {
                    event.consume();
                    if (event.getDeltaY() == 0) {
                        return;
                    }
                    double scaleFactor = (event.getDeltaY() > 0) ? SCALE_DELTA : 1 / SCALE_DELTA;
                    Point2D scrollOffset = figureScrollOffset(scrollContent, scrollPane);
                    group.setScaleX(group.getScaleX() * scaleFactor);
                    group.setScaleY(group.getScaleY() * scaleFactor);
                    repositionScroller(scrollContent, scrollPane, scaleFactor, scrollOffset);
                }
        );

        group.getChildren()
                .add(new Node("Test3", 500, 500));

    }

    private Point2D figureScrollOffset(javafx.scene.Node scrollContent, ScrollPane scroller) {
        double extraWidth = scrollContent.getLayoutBounds().getWidth() - scroller.getViewportBounds().getWidth();
        double hScrollProportion = (scroller.getHvalue() - scroller.getHmin()) / (scroller.getHmax() - scroller.getHmin());
        double scrollXOffset = hScrollProportion * Math.max(0, extraWidth);
        double extraHeight = scrollContent.getLayoutBounds().getHeight() - scroller.getViewportBounds().getHeight();
        double vScrollProportion = (scroller.getVvalue() - scroller.getVmin()) / (scroller.getVmax() - scroller.getVmin());
        double scrollYOffset = vScrollProportion * Math.max(0, extraHeight);
        return new Point2D(scrollXOffset, scrollYOffset);
    }

    private void repositionScroller(javafx.scene.Node scrollContent, ScrollPane scroller, double scaleFactor, Point2D scrollOffset) {
        double scrollXOffset = scrollOffset.getX();
        double scrollYOffset = scrollOffset.getY();
        double extraWidth = scrollContent.getLayoutBounds().getWidth() - scroller.getViewportBounds().getWidth();
        if (extraWidth > 0) {
            double halfWidth = scroller.getViewportBounds().getWidth() / 2;
            double newScrollXOffset = (scaleFactor - 1) * halfWidth + scaleFactor * scrollXOffset;
            scroller.setHvalue(scroller.getHmin() + newScrollXOffset * (scroller.getHmax() - scroller.getHmin()) / extraWidth);
        } else {
            scroller.setHvalue(scroller.getHmin());
        }
        double extraHeight = scrollContent.getLayoutBounds().getHeight() - scroller.getViewportBounds().getHeight();
        if (extraHeight > 0) {
            double halfHeight = scroller.getViewportBounds().getHeight() / 2;
            double newScrollYOffset = (scaleFactor - 1) * halfHeight + scaleFactor * scrollYOffset;
            scroller.setVvalue(scroller.getVmin() + newScrollYOffset * (scroller.getVmax() - scroller.getVmin()) / extraHeight);
        } else {
            scroller.setHvalue(scroller.getHmin());
        }
    }
}
```

The node class:

```
public class Node extends Parent {

    private NodeStatus status = NodeStatus.OK;
    private final Image okImage = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/MasterOK.png"));
    private ImageView image = new ImageView(okImage);
    private final Text label = new Text();
    private final Font font = Font.font("Courier", 20);
    double orgSceneX, orgSceneY;
    double layoutX, layoutY;

    public Node(String labelText) {
        this(labelText, 0, 0);
    }

    public Node(String labelText, double x, double y) {
        label.setText(labelText);
        label.setFont(font);
        label.setLayoutX(okImage.getWidth() + 10);
        label.setLayoutY(okImage.getHeight() / 2 + 10);
        getChildren().add(image);
        getChildren().add(label);
        setLayoutX(x);
        setLayoutY(y);
        setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);
        setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                orgSceneX = t.getSceneX();
                orgSceneY = t.getSceneY();
                layoutX = getLayoutX();
                layoutY = getLayoutY();
            }
        });
        setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                setLayoutX(layoutX + t.getSceneX() - orgSceneX);
                setLayoutY(layoutY + t.getSceneY() - orgSceneY);
            }
        });

    }

    public NodeStatus getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(NodeStatus status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

}

class Delta {

    double x, y;
}
```

and the fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import nodes.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="cqsmonitor.MainWindowController">
    <children>
        <Pane layoutX="666.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="572.0" prefWidth="114.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="14.0">
            <children>
                <TextField layoutY="30.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="114.0" />
                <Label layoutY="12.0" text="Search:" />
                <ChoiceBox layoutY="90.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="114.0" />
                <Label layoutY="73.0" text="View:" />
            </children>
        </Pane>
        <ScrollPane fx:id="scrollPane" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" pannable="true" prefHeight="571.0" prefWidth="644.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="15.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="142.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="14.0">
        </ScrollPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Since nobody answered yet,* here's some code. I don't want to dig into yours and re-invent the wheel.

You can move nodes by dragging with the left mouse button, scale the pane with the mouse wheel, pan the pane with the right mouse button. No ScrollPane needed. However, if you want ScrollBars, you can always add them if you prefer them.

The code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * The canvas which holds all of the nodes of the application.
 */
class PannableCanvas extends Pane {

    DoubleProperty myScale = new SimpleDoubleProperty(1.0);

    public PannableCanvas() {

        setPrefSize(600, 600);
        setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightgrey; -fx-border-color: blue;");

        // add scale transform
        scaleXProperty().bind(myScale);
        scaleYProperty().bind(myScale);

        // logging
        addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, event -> { 
            System.out.println( 
                    "canvas event: " + ( ((event.getSceneX() - getBoundsInParent().getMinX()) / getScale()) + ", scale: " + getScale())
                    );
            System.out.println( "canvas bounds: " + getBoundsInParent());   
                });

    }

    /**
     * Add a grid to the canvas, send it to back
     */
    public void addGrid() {

        double w = getBoundsInLocal().getWidth();
        double h = getBoundsInLocal().getHeight();

        // add grid
        Canvas grid = new Canvas(w, h);

        // don't catch mouse events
        grid.setMouseTransparent(true);

        GraphicsContext gc = grid.getGraphicsContext2D();

        gc.setStroke(Color.GRAY);
        gc.setLineWidth(1);

        // draw grid lines
        double offset = 50;
        for( double i=offset; i < w; i+=offset) {
            // vertical
            gc.strokeLine( i, 0, i, h);
            // horizontal
            gc.strokeLine( 0, i, w, i);
        }

        getChildren().add( grid);

        grid.toBack();
    }

    public double getScale() {
        return myScale.get();
    }

    /**
     * Set x/y scale
     * @param myScale
     */
    public void setScale( double scale) {
        myScale.set(scale);
    }

    /**
     * Set x/y pivot points
     * @param x
     * @param y
     */
    public void setPivot( double x, double y) {
        setTranslateX(getTranslateX()-x);
        setTranslateY(getTranslateY()-y);
    }
}


/**
 * Mouse drag context used for scene and nodes.
 */
class DragContext {

    double mouseAnchorX;
    double mouseAnchorY;

    double translateAnchorX;
    double translateAnchorY;

}

/**
 * Listeners for making the nodes draggable via left mouse button. Considers if parent is zoomed.
 */
class NodeGestures {

    private DragContext nodeDragContext = new DragContext();

    PannableCanvas canvas;

    public NodeGestures( PannableCanvas canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;

    }

    public EventHandler<MouseEvent> getOnMousePressedEventHandler() {
        return onMousePressedEventHandler;
    }

    public EventHandler<MouseEvent> getOnMouseDraggedEventHandler() {
        return onMouseDraggedEventHandler;
    }

    private EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMousePressedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

            // left mouse button => dragging
            if( !event.isPrimaryButtonDown())
                return;

            nodeDragContext.mouseAnchorX = event.getSceneX();
            nodeDragContext.mouseAnchorY = event.getSceneY();

            Node node = (Node) event.getSource();

            nodeDragContext.translateAnchorX = node.getTranslateX();
            nodeDragContext.translateAnchorY = node.getTranslateY();

        }

    };

    private EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseDraggedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

            // left mouse button => dragging
            if( !event.isPrimaryButtonDown())
                return;

            double scale = canvas.getScale();

            Node node = (Node) event.getSource();

            node.setTranslateX(nodeDragContext.translateAnchorX + (( event.getSceneX() - nodeDragContext.mouseAnchorX) / scale));
            node.setTranslateY(nodeDragContext.translateAnchorY + (( event.getSceneY() - nodeDragContext.mouseAnchorY) / scale));

            event.consume();

        }
    };
}

/**
 * Listeners for making the scene's canvas draggable and zoomable
 */
class SceneGestures {

    private static final double MAX_SCALE = 10.0d;
    private static final double MIN_SCALE = .1d;

    private DragContext sceneDragContext = new DragContext();

    PannableCanvas canvas;

    public SceneGestures( PannableCanvas canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
    }

    public EventHandler<MouseEvent> getOnMousePressedEventHandler() {
        return onMousePressedEventHandler;
    }

    public EventHandler<MouseEvent> getOnMouseDraggedEventHandler() {
        return onMouseDraggedEventHandler;
    }

    public EventHandler<ScrollEvent> getOnScrollEventHandler() {
        return onScrollEventHandler;
    }

    private EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMousePressedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

            // right mouse button => panning
            if( !event.isSecondaryButtonDown())
                return;

            sceneDragContext.mouseAnchorX = event.getSceneX();
            sceneDragContext.mouseAnchorY = event.getSceneY();

            sceneDragContext.translateAnchorX = canvas.getTranslateX();
            sceneDragContext.translateAnchorY = canvas.getTranslateY();

        }

    };

    private EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseDraggedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

            // right mouse button => panning
            if( !event.isSecondaryButtonDown())
                return;

            canvas.setTranslateX(sceneDragContext.translateAnchorX + event.getSceneX() - sceneDragContext.mouseAnchorX);
            canvas.setTranslateY(sceneDragContext.translateAnchorY + event.getSceneY() - sceneDragContext.mouseAnchorY);

            event.consume();
        }
    };

    /**
     * Mouse wheel handler: zoom to pivot point
     */
    private EventHandler<ScrollEvent> onScrollEventHandler = new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {

            double delta = 1.2;

            double scale = canvas.getScale(); // currently we only use Y, same value is used for X
            double oldScale = scale;

            if (event.getDeltaY() < 0)
                scale /= delta;
            else
                scale *= delta;

            scale = clamp( scale, MIN_SCALE, MAX_SCALE);

            double f = (scale / oldScale)-1;

            double dx = (event.getSceneX() - (canvas.getBoundsInParent().getWidth()/2 + canvas.getBoundsInParent().getMinX()));
            double dy = (event.getSceneY() - (canvas.getBoundsInParent().getHeight()/2 + canvas.getBoundsInParent().getMinY()));

            canvas.setScale( scale);

            // note: pivot value must be untransformed, i. e. without scaling
            canvas.setPivot(f*dx, f*dy);

            event.consume();

        }

    };


    public static double clamp( double value, double min, double max) {

        if( Double.compare(value, min) < 0)
            return min;

        if( Double.compare(value, max) > 0)
            return max;

        return value;
    }
}



/**
 * An application with a zoomable and pannable canvas.
 */
public class ZoomAndScrollApplication extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        Group group = new Group();

        // create canvas
        PannableCanvas canvas = new PannableCanvas();

        // we don't want the canvas on the top/left in this example => just
        // translate it a bit
        canvas.setTranslateX(100);
        canvas.setTranslateY(100);

        // create sample nodes which can be dragged
        NodeGestures nodeGestures = new NodeGestures( canvas);

        Label label1 = new Label("Draggable node 1");
        label1.setTranslateX(10);
        label1.setTranslateY(10);
        label1.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, nodeGestures.getOnMousePressedEventHandler());
        label1.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, nodeGestures.getOnMouseDraggedEventHandler());

        Label label2 = new Label("Draggable node 2");
        label2.setTranslateX(100);
        label2.setTranslateY(100);
        label2.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, nodeGestures.getOnMousePressedEventHandler());
        label2.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, nodeGestures.getOnMouseDraggedEventHandler());

        Label label3 = new Label("Draggable node 3");
        label3.setTranslateX(200);
        label3.setTranslateY(200);
        label3.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, nodeGestures.getOnMousePressedEventHandler());
        label3.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, nodeGestures.getOnMouseDraggedEventHandler());

        Circle circle1 = new Circle( 300, 300, 50);
        circle1.setStroke(Color.ORANGE);
        circle1.setFill(Color.ORANGE.deriveColor(1, 1, 1, 0.5));
        circle1.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, nodeGestures.getOnMousePressedEventHandler());
        circle1.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, nodeGestures.getOnMouseDraggedEventHandler());

        Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(100,100);
        rect1.setTranslateX(450);
        rect1.setTranslateY(450);
        rect1.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
        rect1.setFill(Color.BLUE.deriveColor(1, 1, 1, 0.5));
        rect1.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, nodeGestures.getOnMousePressedEventHandler());
        rect1.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, nodeGestures.getOnMouseDraggedEventHandler());

        canvas.getChildren().addAll(label1, label2, label3, circle1, rect1);

        group.getChildren().add(canvas);

        // create scene which can be dragged and zoomed
        Scene scene = new Scene(group, 1024, 768);

        SceneGestures sceneGestures = new SceneGestures(canvas);
        scene.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, sceneGestures.getOnMousePressedEventHandler());
        scene.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, sceneGestures.getOnMouseDraggedEventHandler());
        scene.addEventFilter( ScrollEvent.ANY, sceneGestures.getOnScrollEventHandler());

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        canvas.addGrid();

    }
}
```

*Let me know if this doesn't help you at all, then I'll delete the post. I'm not interested in the bounty.*

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look at it.

Comment: This works out of the box. I will try to implement it into my code and post an update once I have the time to realize it.

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you! I have used your example and added my node (a Group) on it. The zoom also works perfectly! I have a question though:

Is it possible to zoom the pane, without zooming its children and mantaining their positions inside the pane? Think of a Google Maps marker. When you zoom in, the marker doesn't become bigger. How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I'll just post an answer to summarize the solution to my problem:

The problem why my nodes where lagging behind was because the had no clue about the scaling that might have occured in the pane one level above. So as a final solution I mixed my code with Roland's answer. if anyone has further optimizations in mind, please post them.

Controller class:

```
public class MainWindowController implements Initializable {

    private final Group group = new Group();
    private static final double MAX_SCALE = 10.0d;
    private static final double MIN_SCALE = .1d;

    @FXML
    private ScrollPane scrollPane;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        ZoomableCanvas canvas = new ZoomableCanvas();
        MasterNode node1 = new MasterNode("Test");
        MasterNode node2 = new MasterNode("Test", 100, 200);
        canvas.getChildren().add(node1);
        canvas.getChildren().add(node2);
        group.getChildren().add(canvas);
        scrollPane.setContent(group);
        scrollPane.addEventHandler(ScrollEvent.ANY, new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {
                double delta = 1.2;

                double scale = canvas.getScale(); // currently we only use Y, same value is used for X
                double oldScale = scale;

                if (event.getDeltaY() < 0) {
                    scale /= delta;
                } else {
                    scale *= delta;
                }

                scale = clamp(scale, MIN_SCALE, MAX_SCALE);

                double f = (scale / oldScale) - 1;

                double dx = (event.getSceneX() - (canvas.getBoundsInParent().getWidth() / 2 + canvas.getBoundsInParent().getMinX()));
                double dy = (event.getSceneY() - (canvas.getBoundsInParent().getHeight() / 2 + canvas.getBoundsInParent().getMinY()));

                canvas.setScale(scale);

                // note: pivot value must be untransformed, i. e. without scaling
                canvas.setPivot(f * dx, f * dy);

                event.consume();
            }
        });

    }

    private double clamp(double value, double min, double max) {

        if (Double.compare(value, min) < 0) {
            return min;
        }

        if (Double.compare(value, max) > 0) {
            return max;
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

The canvas:

```
public class ZoomableCanvas extends Pane {

    DoubleProperty scale = new SimpleDoubleProperty(1.0);

    public ZoomableCanvas() {
        scaleXProperty().bind(scale);
        scaleYProperty().bind(scale);


        getChildren().addListener((Change<? extends javafx.scene.Node> c) -> {
            while (c.next()) {
                if (c.wasAdded()) {
                    for (Node child : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                        ((MasterNode) child).scaleProperty.bind(scale);
                    }
                }
                if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                    for (Node child : c.getRemoved()) {
                        ((MasterNode) child).scaleProperty.unbind();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public double getScale() {
        return scale.get();
    }

    public void setScale(double scale) {
        this.scale.set(scale);
    }

    public void setPivot(double x, double y) {
        setTranslateX(getTranslateX() - x);
        setTranslateY(getTranslateY() - y);
    }
}
```

Node:

```
public class MasterNode extends Parent {

    private NodeStatus status = NodeStatus.OK;
    private final Image okImage = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/MasterOK.png"));
    private ImageView image = new ImageView(okImage);
    private final Text label = new Text();
    private final Font font = Font.font("Courier", 20);
    private DragContext nodeDragContext = new DragContext();
    public DoubleProperty scaleProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty(1.0);
    double orgSceneX, orgSceneY;
    double layoutX, layoutY;

    public MasterNode(String labelText) {
        this(labelText, 0, 0);
    }

    public MasterNode(String labelText, double x, double y) {
        scaleXProperty().bind(scaleProperty);
        scaleYProperty().bind(scaleProperty);
        label.setText(labelText);
        label.setFont(font);
        label.setLayoutX(okImage.getWidth() + 10);
        label.setLayoutY(okImage.getHeight() / 2 + 10);
        getChildren().add(image);
        getChildren().add(label);
        setLayoutX(x);
        setLayoutY(y);
        setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);
        setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                // left mouse button => dragging
                if (!event.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                    return;
                }

                nodeDragContext.setMouseAnchorX(event.getSceneX());
                nodeDragContext.setMouseAnchorY(event.getSceneY());

                Node node = (Node) event.getSource();

                nodeDragContext.setTranslateAnchorX(node.getTranslateX());
                nodeDragContext.setTranslateAnchorY(node.getTranslateY());

            }
        });
        setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                // left mouse button => dragging
                if (!event.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                    return;
                }
                Node node = (Node) event.getSource();
                node.setTranslateX(nodeDragContext.getTranslateAnchorX() + ((event.getSceneX() - nodeDragContext.getMouseAnchorX()) / getScale()));
                node.setTranslateY(nodeDragContext.getTranslateAnchorY() + ((event.getSceneY() - nodeDragContext.getMouseAnchorY()) / getScale()));
                event.consume();
            }
        });

    }

    public double getScale() {
        return scaleProperty.get();
    }

    public void setScale(double scale) {
        scaleProperty.set(scale);
    }

    public NodeStatus getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(NodeStatus status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

}
```