# JavaFX: PannableCanvas: get CenterX/Y

Tags: java, javafx

I've been using a customized PannableCanvas that [was presented here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32415609/1975276), and I've run into a bit of trouble. My software is almost finished, and the last thing I need to do is add support for spawning the Nodes on the center of the screen. So what I did originally was:

```
nodeTranslateX/Y = -pannableCanvas.getTranslateX/Y
```

And that worked until I realized that if you zoom in/out (where scale no longer = 1.0), it completely messes it up and the node starts getting placed in weird spots. So then I tried:

```
nodeTranslateX/Y = -pannableCanvas.getTranslateX/Y * pannableCanvas.getScale()
```

And that didn't work either! It gets thrown even further out of whack.

I tried numerous combinations of transformations such as dividing the scale, inverting the scale, using screenToLocal(), you name it. None of them have worked. The problem is that when you zoom out, the translateX/Y of the canvas is adjusted for the scale, but that gives you stuff like 1500 when the nodes should be spawn with sane coordinates like 300.

Is there a way to get the coordinates of the top-left corner of the screen relative to the canvas? I'm completely at a loss on how to fix this. Again, I just need to be able to spawn the node at the center of the screen. What should I do?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by doing this:

```
Window window = scene.getWindow();
double screenCenterX = (window.getX() + window.getWidth()/2);
double screenCenterY = (window.getY() + window.getHeight()/2);

Point2D point = pannablePane.screenToLocal(screenCenterX, screenCenterY);

double nodeX = point.getX() - MyNodeImplementation.WIDTH/2;
double nodeY = point.getY() - MyNodeImplementation.HEIGHT/2;
```

I had mistaken screenX/Y for being within the window (I.E. center = WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2), but instead you actually have to take the actual window position into account too.